# getchar_unlocked() explanation

Tags: c, ascii, getchar

In this snippet, why is the condition checking whether ch<'0' || ch > '9' necessary.Why can't only the if statement suffice?

```
   #define getcx getchar_unlocked 
 inline void inp( int &n )
  n=0;
  char ch=getcx();
  int sign=1;

 while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' ) // Why is this while loop essential?
  {if(ch=='-')sign=-1; ch=getcx();}

  while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
       n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getcx();
  n=n*sign;
  }
```

Function returns 3454 as 3454 and -3454 as -3454

Comment: Try it for yourself and see if it still works.

Comment: It is a poor man's integer parser. Try some non-digit input an you'll see.

Comment: Also, try entering '34-54' to see what you get.

Comment: The "times ten" optimization looks quite misguided, too: these days, most compilers would optimize multiplication by a constant without explicit shifting.

Comment: @Steger - I tried.On removing the while line, it doesnt take input beyond nos. and -

Comment: @self.- why so? it executes faster than the other options

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I use the gnu gcc compiler . But if, they do, then doesnt it reduce the importance of bit manipulations to an extent ?

Comment: @KrisnaTaapad Bit manipulation that is done for bit manipulation remains important: for example, when you are dealing with bit masks and other similar objects, bit operations are essential. However, in this case `(n<<3)+(n<<1)` is essentially a multiplication of two numbers - `10*n`, "optimized" for computers that use binary representation of numbers and lack fast multiplication unit in the CPU. If you write `10*n` the compiler would either keep it, or replace with shifts and additions, depending on the platform.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -oh, i dont know much about bit masks. Thanks  :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the `while` loop is to skip over all non-digit characters on the way to the first digit, paying attention only to dashes. For example, this code would interpret

```
hello-world123
```

as `-123`

A more likely scenario, though, is that the author of this code fragment wanted to skip over spaces. This kind of code is common in programming competitions, where programmers use the less safe [`getchar_unlocked`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getc_unlocked.html) in order to squeeze out a few microseconds while reading the input.

It is needless to say that this is a very quick and dirty parser, intended for use with extremely clean data.